# How can I handle changing PageModel in code-behind?

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a Xamarin.Forms application using FreshMVVM. Can anybody tell me if I can use binding to handle changing the PageModel in Page's code-behind? E.g. if an event happens in the PageModel like this:

```
public class VideoCallPageModel : BasePageModel
{
    SignalRService signalR;
 ...

    public async override void Init(object initData)
    {
        base.Init(initData);

        signalR = new SignalRService();
        signalR.OnIncomingCall += SignalR_IncomingCall;
        ...

    private void SignalR_IncomingCall(object sender, VideoCallPeer peer)
    {
        ...
    }
```

So I need to handle in Page's code-behind firing this OnIncomingCall event. Is it possible?

Comment: why wouldn't you just have VideoCallPageModel raise it's own event that the page could subscribe to?

Comment: @Jason Could you please give me an example or some reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a custom event in your model

```
public delegate void IncomingCallHandler(object sender, VideoCallPeer e);
public event IncomingCallHandler OnIncomingCall;

private void SignalR_IncomingCall(object sender, VideoCallPeer peer)
{  
    if (OnIncomingCall == null) return;
    
    OnIncomingCall(this, peer);
}
```

then your page can subscribe to it with an event handler